# Weak star convergence in $L^{\infty}$ and strong convergence in $L^2$ imply strong convergence in $L^p$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

I can't see why the following would hold. Can someone please point out why?

> If $f_n$ convergence weak-* in $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$, and converges
> strongly in $L^2(\Omega)$, then it must also converge strongly in
> $L^p(\Omega)$ for $1 \leq p < \infty$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
A standard application of Hölder's inequality gives
$$
\|g\|_{L^p} \le \|g\|_{L^2}^\theta \|g\|_{L^\infty}^{1-\theta}$$
for a proper choice of $\theta$.

Comment: This is not the Holder's I am familiar with. If $p=1$, then I see $\|1\cdot g\|_1 \leq C \|g\|_2$. I don't see what is happening for $p>1$. Can you please elaborate more? Thanks

Comment: Try to apply the Hölder inequality to the product $g^\theta \cdot g^{1-\theta}$.